# Linux framebuffer bits_per_pixel vs offset values for determining pixel format

Tags: linux, graphics, 2d, framebuffer, pixelformat

The `fb_var_screeninfo` has several fields that I can use for determining the pixel formats, most notably `bits_per_pixel` and `length` / `offset` fields for red / green / blue / alpha ("transp") channels.

Now I noticed some apparent redundancy. If I analyze the length fields, I already know the bits per pixel, so checking `bits_per_pixel` should be unnecessary. But, there's theory and there's practice. I can imagine for example that in some fringe cases, the length values would not be populated properly, while `bits_per_pixel` would always be valid.

So. My question is: Can I rely on the length and offset fields to always be valid, and just ignore the `bits_per_pixel` field?